# Destructor call and pointers

Tags: c++

Here's my question
say I have a function, which consists of something like this:

```
void function() {  
    entity e; //entity is just a class  
    entities.push_back(e); //entities is a vector of entity objects  
}
```

Here's whats troubling me. 'e' contains a pointer to another object. When the destructor for entity is called, it deletes that pointer. Since both 'e' and the entity in entities point to the same place, if I do something to that pointer from entities, (outside of the function) it gives an error, because whatever was at the pointer was deleted as soon as the function returned. What is the best way to fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

C++ is a "copy-based" language and for example a container of `Entity` will indeed put **copies** of the entities you give it inside the container.

Copies are made in C++ in many places so it's better that either your class supports them correctly or that you forbid them completely.

Your class contains a pointer to other data: what should happen when you make a copy of an instance of that class? If copying the pointer is ok, then clearly it cannot be ok to delete the pointed object in the destructor because still existing copies would be pointing to a deleted object.

There is a simple rule that helps avoiding this kind of mistake and is known as "the rule of three". If you have coded explicitly either

- a copy constructor
- a destructor
- an assignment operator

in your class then most probably you need all of three of them.

In this case you've a destructor that is not the default one (because deletes the pointed object) so you also need to tell what to do in case of copy construction or assignment.

If you prefer that class to be non-copyable then just ensure that

```
struct Entity {
    Object *o;

    Entity(Object *o) : o(o) {
        ...
    }

    ~Entity() {
        delete o;
    }

private:
    // Taboo... this should just never happen!!!
    // Here is a declaration, but no implementation will be written
    Entity(const Entity& other);      // Copy constructor
    Entity& operator=(const Entity&); // Assignment
};
```

declaring forbidden operations `private` will ensure that user code will never call them (it would be a compile-time error), and just declaring them without providing an implementation will ensure that even the class code itself will not call them by mistake (you'd get a link-time error).

In this specific case however this would forbid your code to put `Entity` instances inside containers (elements inside containers must be copied around). You could put `Entity` **pointers** inside a container (pointers can be copied so an `std::vector<Entity *>` for `entities` would be legal) but you would be in charge to handle the correct lifetime for the objects (who should call the destructor and when should that happen?).

If on the other hand you have a pointer to data inside the class and you want to **allow** making a copy of an instance of the class you can either:

- Copy also the pointed data
- Share pointed data between different instances

for the second solution a common approach is using "reference-counted" pointers, i.e. the pointed data "knows" how many pointers are referencing it and is destroyed only when this count reaches 0.

Comment: Thank you. Very descriptive in my eyes.

Comment: Agreed, very clear and useful description of an important issue.

Comment: With c++11, `=delete` is better than private without implementation. (and "rule of 3" becomes "rule of 5"). There are good smart pointers (unique_ptr/shared_ptr).

Answer (score 3):

changing the pointer to the shared object to contain a `shared_ptr` would be a simple solution.

Comment: It would also be a terrible solution if done without understanding the reasons behind it.

Comment: Hmm. can you give an example of how to do this?

Comment: @qdii Using a shared pointer shares *ownership*.  It probably isn't appropriate to dole out ownership to everyone that wants to use an object.  To wit, you generally don't want to make everyone responsible for deciding when an object is destroyed.

Comment: @6502 It could be.  If OP actually wants to copy objects with pointers into containers, then it is a viable and cheap strategy in many situations.

Comment: @TomKerr: I'm not saying that using `shared_ptr` is a bad idea, actually in many cases it could be a good idea (even if I like more an intrusive reference counted approach). The bad idea is to use `shared_ptr` without understanding what the problem is and what the implications and limitations are. Just not thinking is rarely the correct solution, especially in C++.

Answer (score 3):

This is because you have violated the [rule of three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C++_programming%29): if you have a destructor, you almost certainly need to have a copy constructor and an assignment operator as well.

Of course the best way of dealing with pointers is to find a way of not having pointers at all ("the rule of zero"): in situations like that compiler-generated destructors, constructors, and assignment operators would take care of managing the resources automatically for you.

Comment: How would I go about applying this?

Comment: @user2159051 Applying the rule of three is easy, but adds to maintenance: add a copy constructor and an assignment operator to `entity` so that the object pointed to by the pointer inside `e` gets copied, and a new pointer is assigned to the copy of `entity`. Applying the "rule of zero" is harder - rather than sticking a pointer to some object into `entity`, put the object itself. This works better for small objects than for bigger ones, where using a pointer may be a better choice.

Answer (score 0):

If the entity class has a destructor, it should also define a copy and copy assignment operator by the [rule of three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C++_programming%29).

Unfortunately, this presumably means you would have to copy the item pointed to in the object, so that when destroyed the copy of the object does not delete an item that will be later deleted by some other copy.  "Unfortunately" because creating a duplicate of the pointed to item is often undesirable; in this case, you have a design conundrum -- although Tom Kerr's suggestion WRT `shared_ptr` is a nice option.

Another solution would be to forbid copies, by making the copy constructor private, or (C++11) by using `= delete`, and making `entity` an array of pointers instead (and `push_back(&e)`).